# Is it possible to access a shared TPH column in EF Core without using intermediate classes?

Tags: entity-framework-core, table-per-hierarchy

When using [shared columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#shared-columns) in an EF Core TPH setup, is it possible to **access the shared column during projection**?

```cs
    class Program
    {
        public static readonly ILoggerFactory MyLoggerFactory
            = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => { 
                builder.AddConsole(); 
            });

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var context = new ClientContext())
            {
                context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();

                var actions = await context.Actions
                    .Select(a => new
                    {
                        Id = a.Id,

                        // this works - but really messy and complex in real world code
                        Message = (a as ActionA).Message ?? (a as ActionB).Message,

                        // this throws "Either the query source is not an entity type, or the specified property does not exist on the entity type."
                        // is there any other way to access the shared column Message?
                        // Message = EF.Property<string>(a, "Message"),
                    })
                    .ToListAsync();

                actions.ForEach(a => Console.WriteLine(a.Id + a.Message));
            }
        }

        public class ActionBase
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }

            // ... other shared properties
        }

        public class ActionA : ActionBase
        {
            // shared with B
            [Required]
            [Column("Message")]
            public string Message { get; set; }

            // ... other specific properties
        }

        public class ActionB : ActionBase
        {
            // shared with A
            [Required]
            [Column("Message")]
            public string Message { get; set; }

            // ... other specific properties
        }

        public class ActionC : ActionBase
        {
            public string SomethingElse { get; set; }

            // ... other specific properties
        }

        class ClientContext : DbContext
        {
            protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
            {
                // TO USE SQL
                //optionsBuilder
                //    .UseLoggerFactory(MyLoggerFactory)
                //    .UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=TPHSharedColumn;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Connect Timeout=30")
                //    .EnableSensitiveDataLogging(false);
                // TO USE INMEMORY
                optionsBuilder
                   .UseLoggerFactory(MyLoggerFactory)
                   .UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            }

            protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
            {
                base.OnModelCreating(builder);

                builder.Entity<ActionA>().HasData(new ActionA()
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Message = "A"
                });
                builder.Entity<ActionB>().HasData(new ActionB()
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    Message = "B"
                });
                builder.Entity<ActionC>().HasData(new ActionC()
                {
                    Id = 3,
                    SomethingElse = "C"
                });
            }

            public DbSet<ActionBase> Actions { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

In this simple example, it would of course be possible to move `Message` to the base class - but that would make it possible to accidentally add an `ActionC` with a `Message` since I would need to remove the `Required` attribute.

I also know I could add a `ActionWithRequiredMessage` intermediate class to inherit `ActionA` and `ActionB` with, but again - in the much more complex real world example this is not feasible since there are also other shared columns and C# does not allow inheriting from multiple classes - and EF Core does not seem to like to use interfaces for this.

I simply would like to find a way to **directly access the shared column** - and use it in a projection.

Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find it documented, but in EF Core 5.x you can access the shared column using *any* of the derived entities having a property mapped to it, e.g. all these work

```cs
Message = (a as ActionA).Message,
```

```cs
Message = (a as ActionB).Message,
```

```cs
Message = ((ActionA)a).Message,
```

```cs
Message = ((ActionB)a).Message,
```

Comment: I'd love to have this working, but when I try it in the sample code above (both 5.0.7 and 6.0-preview5) it will only resolve Message for the type given. So the output of the above program will be 1A, 2, 3 if I use ActionA type, or 1, 2B, 3 if I use ActionB (and not 1A, 2B, 3 as wanted).

Comment: Have you tried it with a real database provider? Tested your example exactly as is, EF Core 5.0.7/SqlServer, and getting (1, "A"), (2, "B") and (3, null) using any of the above methods.

Comment: you are absolutely correct, it does work in the Sql Server provider. I always write test first using InMemory, so it never occurred to me that it could be a provider issue. I'll accept this answer and submit an issue with the EF Core team to see if InMemory could get feature parity with SQL Server or if it's a bug in SQL Server I'd like to know before using this workaround in my code. (so that I do not get hit by future "upgrades"..)

Comment: filed https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/25210